# How to make prediction after model registration in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I created a simply model and then registered in azure. How can I make a prediction?

```
from sklearn import svm
import joblib
import numpy as np

# customer ages
X_train = np.array([50, 17, 35, 23, 28, 40, 31, 29, 19, 62])
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 1)
# churn y/n
y_train = ["yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes"]

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

joblib.dump(value=clf, filename="churn-model.pkl")
```

Registration:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
ws = Workspace.get(name="myworkspace", subscription_id='My_subscription_id', resource_group='ML_Lingaro')

from azureml.core.model import Model
model = Model.register(workspace=ws, model_path="churn-model.pkl", model_name="churn-model-test")
```

Prediction:

```
from azureml.core.model import Model
import os

model = Model(workspace=ws, name="churn-model-test")
X_test = np.array([50, 17, 35, 23, 28, 40, 31, 29, 19, 62])
model.predict(X_test) ????
```

Error: `AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

great question -- I also had the same misconception starting out. The missing piece is that there's a difference between model 'registration' and model 'deployment'. Registration is simply for tracking and for easy downloading at a later place and time. Deployment is what you're after, making a model available to be scored against.

There's a [whole section in the docs about deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where?tabs=python&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003930). My suggestion would be to deploy it locally first for testing.

Comment: is there a way to load the model file (and environment) without having to "deploy" it? deploying to a virtual machine seems like overkill and is expensive in some cases, especially if all I want is to load the model to predict.

Comment: registering a model to Azure ML Service makes a named pointer to where the `.pkl` file is saved in blob. So if you want to download the model on another machine/service/pipeline, you can use the Azure ML SDK to get the model and download it. Check out the Model class docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-core-model-model-download

Comment: Thanks @Anders. Going to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide an bit more up-to-date answer in case someone finds this online.

The reason why the proposed workflow doesn't work is because `joblib.dump` creates just a file. There is no way for Azure Machine Learning to know that such file contains a Scikit-Learn model so when loading the model back, it's still "just a file".

The simplest way to implement the given workflow is using MLflow, which is compatible with Azure ML:

First, ensure you have MLflow installed:

```bash
pip install mlflow azureml-mlflow
```

Configure MLflow in case you haven't. There are multiple ways to do this step and the easier one depends on your setting. Check [Configure MLflow for Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-mlflow-configure-tracking?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=python%2Cmlflow)

```py
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(mlflow_tracking_uri)
```

Then, your code will look as follows:

```py
from sklearn import svm
import joblib
import numpy as np

# customer ages
X_train = np.array([50, 17, 35, 23, 28, 40, 31, 29, 19, 62])
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 1)
# churn y/n
y_train = ["yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes"]

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

mlflow.sklearn.log_model(clf, artifact_path="classifier", registered_model_name="churn-model-test")
```

Then this model can be loaded with `mlflow.<flavor>.load_model()`:

```py
my_model = mlflow.sklearn.load_model("models:/churn-model-test/latest")
X_test = np.array([50, 17, 35, 23, 28, 40, 31, 29, 19, 62])
my_model.predict(X_test)
```

To learn more about how to use MLflow with Azure Machine Learning visit [MLflow and Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-mlflow).